Shapefiles for Unicorporated Areas in USA
I have been looking for the countywise shapefile for all the unincorporated areas in USA but couldn't able to find it anywhere, I have tried using tigerline site and also some GIS site. Where can I find the countywise shape file for all the unincorporated areas  in USA
